# What gem do you advise me to use to implement a simple "Contact us" form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, rubygems

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am planning to add a simple "Contact us" form to my application in order to make it possible that a user can contact our team. For that I would like to run validation and "friends" functionalities and (to avoid to implement that myself and) to use a third party software, but...

*... what gem (or plugin) do you advice to use? what is the most widely "approved" gem for this kind of things?*

Of course I would like to use a gem in "active developing" (that is, whose developers are active).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not to complicated to do it on your own (pretty fast)? I hardly think it needs a separate gem to do this (especially if for example [contact_us](https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us) requires additional dependencies (formtastic)).

As for me, it's just a simple form, with action directed to your own Rails mailer.

See: [ActionMailer in Rails 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), [Form helpers in Rails 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: I would like to add also validations and friends for my form.

Comment: friends? as for validation, then you should create a model (without migration, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315850/rails-model-without-database))

Comment: "friends" means 'ActiveModel::Conversion', 'ActiveModel::Naming', ... because I know about 'ActiveModel'.

Comment: The stackoverflow question you posted is a little bit dated.

Comment: oops, sorry about that. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858189/rails-3-display-validation-errors-for-a-form-not-saving-an-activerecord-model)

Comment: also, you can create a model, without a migration, and in controller in `create` don't invoke `save` but `valid`. it will perform validations, but don't save the model

Answer (score 5):

Generally I would go with a rails engine to add this functionality and the [**contact_us**](https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us) plugin an excellent example, it's also under active development (last commit 5 days ago) so you can be sure it's not abandon-ware.

Comment: The 'contact_us' gem require 'Formtastic' (that I don't know very well)... is it better to use "directly" 'Formtastic' instead of 'contact_us'? What about 'Formtastic'?

Comment: Formtastic is a plugin that adds some syntactic sugar to the rails form builder, it wouldn't provide contact form functionality on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contact Us gem via this link: https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us The documentation is clear and you can use it simply.

As I know by using it, it doesn't need any additional dependency like "formtastic".

Features:

- Validation
- Easy/Add remove fields
- Simple configuration